# A formula for the area in terms of local parametrisation

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X(s,t)$ be a local parametrisation then

$\mid \mid X_{v} \times X_{u}\mid \mid = \sqrt{EG-F^2}$

where $E=<X_{u},X_{u}>$, $F=<X_{u},X_{v}>$ and $G=<X_{v},X_{v}>$, the components of the first fundamental form.

Does anyone know a proof of this?

Comment: I suspect you meant $\Vert X_u  \times X_v \Vert$ in your first equation.  And then the parametrization is $X(u, v)$.  Am I right?

Comment: See pages 40-41 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). It's a special case of the [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to see if we recall that

$\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert = \Vert X_u \Vert \Vert X_v \Vert \vert \sin \theta \vert, \tag 1$

where $\theta$ is the angle 'twixt the vectors $X_u$ and $V_v$; then

$\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert^2 = \Vert X_u \Vert^2 \Vert X_v \Vert^2 \vert \sin \theta \vert^2; \tag 2$

likewise $F$ may be expressed in terms of $\cos \theta$:

$F = \langle X_u, X_v \rangle = \Vert X_u \Vert \Vert X_v \Vert \cos \theta, \tag 3$

whence

$F^2 = \Vert X_u \Vert^2 \Vert X_v \Vert^2 \vert \cos \theta \vert^2; \tag 4$

then

$\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert^2 + F^2 = \Vert X_u \Vert^2 \Vert X_v \Vert^2 \vert \sin \theta \vert^2 + \Vert X_u \Vert^2 \Vert X_v \Vert^2 \vert \cos \theta \vert^2$
$= \Vert X_u \Vert^2 \Vert X_v \Vert^2(\vert \sin \theta \vert^2 + \vert \cos \theta \vert^2 ) = \Vert X_u \Vert^2 \Vert X_v \Vert^2; \tag 5$

also,

$E = \langle X_u, X_u \rangle = \Vert X_u \Vert^2; \tag 6$

$G = \langle X_v, X_u \rangle = \Vert X_v \Vert^2; \tag 7$

we fold (6) and (7) into (5), yielding

$\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert^2 + F^2 = EG, \tag 8$

that is,

$\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert^2 = EG - F^2, \tag 8$

and finally

$\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert = \sqrt{EG - F^2}, \tag 9$

$OE\Delta$.

For more on formulas (1) and (3), see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations).